# Visual Studio - Change regular existing file to link

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I added several files to my project and I want to change this files to be [added as links](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj714082%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Is there better way other than deleting those files and add it again as link?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do this by editing the project file directly.  Compare the element for a linked file with that of a local file.

```
<Compile Include="path\to\file\LinkedFile.cs">
  <Link>LinkedFile.cs</Link>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="LocalFile.cs" />
```

If you had a lot of files, you could write a script to do this for you, but for a relatively small number of files it is likely easier to delete and re-add them.